# How to estimate the runtime when the input size is unknown

Tags: algorithm

I am learning how to analyze the algorithm (First 5 chapters) by myself using this book: [Introduction of Algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Introduction_to_Algorithms). Assume I have the following simple algorithm (I made it up):

```
for i <- 0 to 100
  for j <- 1 to 2000
     if (i*10 + j*20 = n)
         c <- c+1
```

Now, if I want to estimate the running time of this algorithm for a **specific** input size, say `n= 500`, I'd say:

The running time in worst case is `T(n) = 100*2000*500 = 10 * 10^7`. However, when I want to generalize for any input size, i.e. `n`, I don't know how to do this! Kindly, can someone enlighten me?

Thank you

Comment: Big-O already generalizes over n as n -> infinity. So it would be, for example: `O(n*n) = O(n^2)` (replacing n for both i and j since they are independent and not further qualified).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current running time is wrong. Since you always loop through all `i` and `j` values, it takes a total of `100*2000` iterations. This is independent of your `n` value. However, if you assume your unknowns are the max `i` and `j` values, denoted by `I` and `J` respectively, you could say your algorithm has running time `O(IJ)`. You're on the right track, just replace your constants for variables.

Comment: Thank you very much .. Well explained :)

Comment: I apologize for coming back again. Now I understand that the runtime for my algorithm above is independent of n, i.e. it takes `100*2000` for any input size. So, how do I represent this is Big oh notation? Is it acceptable to say `O(100*2000)` ?

Comment: Your algorithm is constant with respect to `n`, so you would say `O(1)`. I gave the Big-O for the scenario where you varied `I` and `J`

Comment: Thank you so much for answering this. Really appreciate it. Actually, I don't understand what do you mean by: `Your algorithm is constant with respect to n, so you would say O(1)` I think there is something hidding about the difference between the runtime of algorithm and loop iterations

Comment: Asymptotic analysis looks at how the algorithm grows with respect to the size of its input. In your original problem, (what I am calling) `I` and `J` are fixed at 100 and 2000. your original input was only `n`. The algorithm would run for the same amount regardless of how big `n` was. If `n` was zero, it would still take 200k iterations. If `n` was $\infty$, it would still take 200k iterations. The algorithm run time does not depend on how big `n` is.